# React Native - useEffect / setState - fetching data from api

Tags: react-native

I'm learning RN and writing a simple app about lottery results.

I am facing this problem:

I need to print the results that i am fetching from an api when the component mounts, using useEffect and setState. Everything works regarding the api call and the item construction, i can console.log the resulting array [loadedResults] which i want to be 'results' in the state.

But, the state its not being modified so the state object remains always empty.

I am clearly missing something in the setState step.

I have tried to make it a function and also using variable.then(...).

I am using a for loop because there are hundreds of results in the api and i only want 10 of them.

this is my code:

```
const ResultadosScreen = props => {

   const [results, setResults] = useState({});

   useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const response = await fetch('apiUrlGoesHere');
            // response.json().then((response => setResults(response)));
            const resData = await response.json();
            const pastResults = resData.past;
            const loadedResults = [];
            for (let r = 0; r < 11; r++){
                loadedResults.push(
                    new FakeResult(
                        r,
                        pastResults[r].drawingDate.substring(0,10),
                        pastResults[r].nr,
                        pastResults[r].numbers
                        )

                );
            }
            console.log(loadedResults); // I GET THE EXPECTED 10 ITEMS IN THIS CONSOLE LOG

            (loadedResults => setResults(loadedResults)) //HERE IS WHERE IM MISSING SOMETHING


        }
        fetchData()
   });
   console.log(results);

//I GET UNDEFINED FROM THIS CONSOLE LOG

 return (
        <View style={styles.screen}><Text style={styles.headerTitle}>{}</Text></View>
 );
};

export default ResultadosScreen;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try just `setResults(loadedResults)` instead of `(loadedResults => setResults(loadedResults))`

Comment: yes that works. thanks very much Orlandster.

Now i get an infinite loop as the useEffect doesnt have any dependency and i need to set a cleanup function, but I dont know how, any help with this?? thanks!